# Getting Unauthorised Full authentication is required to access this resource in Oauth2 Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Oauth2 in Spring Boot and I am using JDBC token store to store the JWT tokens. This is my `AuthorizationServerConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizationServerConfig.class);
    static final String MERCHANT_ID = "merchant-id";
    static final String MERCHANT_SECRET = "merchant-secret-bcrypted-value";
    static final String CUSTOMER_ID = "customer-id";
    static final String CUSTOMER_SECRET = "customer-secret-bcrypted-value";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1 * 60 ;
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 5 * 60 ;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Resource(name = "UserService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("accessTokenConverter");
        System.out.println("accessTokenConverter");
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("asagasdg");


        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("tokenStore");
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }
    @Bean
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore() throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore tokenApprovalStore = new TokenApprovalStore();
        tokenApprovalStore.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return tokenApprovalStore;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("configure");
        configurer
                .jdbc(dataSource)
//                .inMemory()
                .withClient(MERCHANT_ID)
                .secret(MERCHANT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT)
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).
                refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .and()
                .withClient(CUSTOMER_ID)
                .secret(CUSTOMER_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT)
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).and()
                .build()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("configure below");
        endpoints
                .pathMapping("/oauth/token","/api/v1/oauth/token")
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }



    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() throws Exception {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

So whenever I try to hit this url `BASE_URL/api/v1/oauth/token` with the `userid` and `secret` as `Basic-Auth` in Postman along with another `username`, `password` and `grant_type=password` I get this error

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

The in-memory was authentication was working fine but when I created the databases `oauth_access_token`, `oauth_refresh_token` and `oauth_client_details` to save and retrieve the JWTs from database, I am getting that error.

This is my `ResourceServerConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("resource server configurer "+resources);
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("resource server config");
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("api/v1/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/","/css/**","/js/**","/lib/**","/img/**","/scss/**","/templates/**","/device-mockups/**","/vendor/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());


    }

}
```

And this is my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "UserService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("authenticationManagerBean");
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("globalUserDetails");
        auth

                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("bcryptEncoder");
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("configure ");


        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/api/v1/oauth/token","/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                ;
    }


    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

I don't know what I am missing. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have Headers set in Postman.
Key: Content-Type     Value: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

You might have, but you didn't mention. Maybe it helps.

Also, I notice you didn't give permission for all to get a token. Try this in your AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
    public void configure(
            AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
            throws Exception {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
´´´
```

Comment: Postman is adding this `Key: Content-Type Value: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header
And I also tried another solution but the problem is still there.

Comment: Sorry, can't help any more.